# Rails 4.1 application secret is blank at runtime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have added some secrets to the new secrets.yml file in 4.1. According to the [release notes](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html#config/secrets.yml), the new secrets are accessed via `Rails.application.secrets.some_secret`. In rails console, this works. However, at runtime these values are not available. I have tried putting the secrets in each environment and outside environments entirely.

secrets.yml
`development: 
   secret_key_base: secret_key 
   some_secret: a_secret`

rails console
`R2.1.2 :001 > Rails.application.secrets
     => {:secret_key_base=>"secret_key", :some_secret=>"a_secret"}`

a controller method
`puts "secret #{Rails.application.secrets.some_secret}"
"secret "`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have restarted your server after modifying the `secrets.yml` file. Anything in `config` (excepting locale files) are only loaded once, at server start - modifying anything will require a server restart.

Comment: I'm still a bit new to rails and didn't think to try that. Of course it worked, and I feel a bit silly for it. Thanks!